# Pandas apply two argument with Spacy

Tags: python, label, apply, spacy

```
 df.head()
        lang    text
    0  eng      Johnnet went out on the field and felt under her feet..
    1  eng      John was shocked by this statement..
    2  de        Heute hat Marie köstlich gegessen und..
```

I have a dataframe with different languages that why i have a dictionary of two languages spacy :

```
eng_nlp= spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')
de_nlp= spacy.load('de_core_news_lg')

spacy_lang = {
    'de': de_nlp,
    'eng': eng_nlp
}
```

I wrote a function that looks displays only people in the column depending on the language.

```
def label_lang(lang,text):
    model = spacy_lang[lang]
    doc = model(text)
    for ent in  doc.ents:
         if  (ent.label_ == 'PERSON'):
                 return ent.text
```

NOW I WANT TO APPLY THIS TO THE COLUMN df['text'], BUT I GET AN ERROR

```
df.apply( lambda x: label_lang(spacy_lang[x],x['text']),axis = 1)
```

TypeError: unhashable type: 'Series'

I don't understand what I should use as an argument function (spacy_lang)

Comment: `x` is a Series. You can't use `spacy_lang[x]` since the `x` here needs to be a string. You probably have a column with `language` name, and if yes, then use `spacy_lang[x['language']]`

Comment: Please provide a sample of your dataframe.

Comment: My dataframe consists only of the two columns lang(eng,de) and text (some text).So I created a dictionary to download spacy,and then use for labels

Comment: Please run `df.head(3)` and add the output to the question.

Comment: i edit my question and add my dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x` is a series, not a string, thus you can't use `spacy_lang[x]` as the dictionary key type expected here is a string. In this case, you need to use `spacy_lang[x['lang']]` instead of `spacy_lang[x]` in the lambda.

More, if you get the model in the lambda, you need not re-try getting the model inside the `label_lang` function. Look, you have `label_lang(spacy_lang[x]....` and `model = spacy_lang[lang]`, where the latter already holds the spacy model in the `lang` variable.

You can use

```py
import spacy
import pandas as pd

eng_nlp= spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')
de_nlp= spacy.load('de_core_news_lg')
spacy_lang = {'de': de_nlp,'eng': eng_nlp}

def label_lang(model,text):
    doc = model(text)
    for ent in  doc.ents:
         if  (ent.label_ == 'PERSON'):
                 return ent.text

df = pd.DataFrame({'lang': ['eng','eng', 'de'], 'text':[
    'Johnnet went out on the field and felt under her feet..', 
    'John was shocked by this statement..',
    'Heute hat Marie köstlich gegessen und']})

print(df.apply( lambda x: label_lang(spacy_lang[x['lang']],x['text']),axis = 1))
```

Output:

```
0    None
1    John
2    None
```

Comment: But i got error : NameError: name 'spacy_lang' is not defined ,he doesn't see this in the function

Comment: @Rory See the updated snippet that is test and working.

Comment: Oops im sorry, that's worked ! Thank you!